# Replace chars not in string in C#

Tags: c#

What is the best way to upper string and replaces chars that are not in string by a '-' in C#?

```
string allowedChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$_/+-.0123456789";
string str = "FoOB@R";
```

Should return: "FOOB-R"

EDIT:
I tried with Regex but i forgot the "^" at the beginning of the pattern:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/dlrd3A

```
string str = "FoOb@R".ToUpper();
Regex r = new Regex("[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$_/+-.0123456789]");
String result = r.Replace(str, "-");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I would look for using linq but I'm beginner in this syntax and don't know how to begin.
But is linq more speed than regex?

I forgot to post my .NET fiddle code so please don't jugging peoples so quickly ;-) !

Comment: Have you tried anything?....

Comment: I am looking for ...

Comment: side remark: partly very confusing title :) how do you replace something that is not there ;P

Comment: The way SO works is that you show what you have tried and we can help correct it - but it is not a code service

Comment: Please consider reading [ask] on how to improve the question. Meanwhile this link could help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Be clear -  Be elaborated - Be helpful  - These all are mandatory in SO

Comment: I was searching using linq but maybe Regex is better

Comment: "I was searching usin linq but maybe Regex is better" - What is your definition of "good" ?

Comment: Fortunately the guillotine no longer exists. They would have cut off my head for forgetting to post my code ...

Comment: I added the snippet to the question if you don't mind. 4 lines of code really aren't too much to be included in the question directly.

Comment: @Fildor true, i should copy paste the code instead of url ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression will do that for you:

```
Regex r = new Regex("[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$_/+-.0123456789]");
String result = r.Replace("FoOb@R".ToUpper(), "-");
```

We define a list of your allowed characters inside square brackets, this makes a character class which means "match any of these single characters".. but we actually want the opposite of that, so we prefix with caret ^. This inverses the meaning, so it becomes "any character not in this list".

The code line that does the replacement with `-` is then easy to understand - any characters in the foobar string that are not in the list of characters in the character class, are replaced by hyphen. The call to `ToUpper()` makes the string uppercase before replacement. Make sure you do the uppercasing before, and not after, because your character class has only uppercase chars and regex are case sensitive by default. Putting lowercase chars into this replace operation would result in a lot more hyphens in the output :)

Comment: "Regular expression will do that for you:" no, actually you do that for him :)

Comment: LOL (enter at least 15 characters)

Comment: Thanks i tried Regex but forgot the "^" at the beginning of the pattern

Answer (score 4):

What is *best*? LINQ is easy:

```
str = str.ToUpper();
var allowed = str.Select(c => allowedChars.Contains(c) ? c : '-');
str = new string(allowed.ToArray());
```

Comment: @GiladGreen: maybe he had no idea and LINQ can help to simplify such tasks very much. Was very lil effort for me so i've posted.

Comment: @GiladGreen While I generally agree with you, I do not think we need to be so harsh here. He is not _really_ calling for code. He wants to be hinted towards a method. That's at least my personal interpretation of the question. So I am not saying you are wrong, but I really do see no problem in what Tim did here. - Maybe this is better suited for meta ... though.

Comment: Correction:
var allowed = str.Select(c => allowedChars.Contains(char.ToLower(c)) || allowedChars.Contains(char.ToUpper(c)) ? c : '-');

Comment: @AdhirajJaryal: not `ToLower`/`ToUpper`. I have edited my answer, best is an initial `ToUpper`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Cool. I like the way you wrote it.

Comment: @AdhirajJaryal If you put backticks ` around code in comments it becomes `formatted like code`

Comment: `var allowed = str.Select(c => allowedChars.Contains(char.ToLower(c)) || 
                                        allowedChars.Contains(char.ToUpper(c)) ? c : '-');`

Answer (score 0):

```
        string allowedChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$_/+-.0123456789";
        string str = "FoOB@R";

        string upperCaseStr = str.ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine("Before:" upperCaseStr);              
        foreach (char ch in upperCaseStr)
        {
            if (!allowedChars.Contains(ch))
                upperCaseStr = upperCaseStr.Replace(ch, '-');
        }            
        Console.WriteLine("After:" upperCaseStr);
```